# What is the function of uiautomator apks present on the python wrapper for uiautomator 2

Tags: android-uiautomator

I am trying to read and understand how python wrapper for uiautomator2 works. What is the function of uiautomator apks present inside libs and how does this whole framework work?

Also, where did they come from? I could not find source code of these apks.
https://github.com/openatx/uiautomator2

Answer (score 0):

uiautomator apk are there to handle ui commands on phone.
python-uiautomator2 is a python-wrapper, which allows

1. scripting with Python on computer
2. controlling the mobile with computer with/without usb connection
3. screen-casting exact
4. Real time device controlling

## Installation

```
Connect ONLY ONE mobile to the computer with developer-mode open, 
make sure adb devices works
Install packages: pip3 install -U uiautomator2 weditor
Install daemons to the mobile: python/python3 -m uiautomator2 init
```

The weditor is a standalone web-server to interact with the mobile through browser.

## Basic Usage

## Connection

```
Connect the mobile by wifi and run below python script
import uiautomator2 as u2
d = u2.connect('192.168.31.37')
print(d.info)
```

(or)

```
Connect the mobile by USB and run below python script
import uiautomator2 as u2
d = u2.connect('mobile-serial')  # get from "adb devices"
print(d.info)
```

## Key events

```
d.screen_on()
d.screen_off()
d.press('home')
d.press('back')
```

for full details please follow the below link
[uiautomator2 doc](https://pkuwwt.github.io/programming/2020-03-15-android-ui-automator-python/)

Comment: Your answer does not address the main question of verifying the safety of these APKs by inspecting their source code and building them from source.